# How to use officegen with Angular application to generate a word document?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have created a functional Angular application which contains multiple grids (created with ag-grid). Now, I need to extract that information in a report in the form of a word DOcument.
Using the officegen module:
[Officegen module npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/officegen)

> generateReport.js

```
const officegen = require('officegen')
const fs = require('fs')

// Create an empty Word object:
let docx = officegen('docx')

// Officegen calling this function after finishing to generate the docx document:
docx.on('finalize', function(written) {
  console.log(
    'Finish to create a Microsoft Word document.'
  )
})

// Officegen calling this function to report errors:
pptx.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})

// Create a new paragraph:
let pObj = docx.createP()

pObj.addText('Simple')
pObj.addText(' with color', { color: '000088' })
pObj.addText(' and back color.', { color: '00ffff', back: '000088' })

pObj = docx.createP()

pObj.addText('Since ')
pObj.addText('officegen 0.2.12', {
  back: '00ffff',
  shdType: 'pct12',
  shdColor: 'ff0000'
}) // Use pattern in the background.
pObj.addText(' you can do ')
pObj.addText('more cool ', { highlight: true }) // Highlight!
pObj.addText('stuff!', { highlight: 'darkGreen' }) // Different highlight color.

pObj = docx.createP()

pObj.addText('Even add ')
pObj.addText('external link', { link: 'https://github.com' })
pObj.addText('!')

pObj = docx.createP()

pObj.addText('Bold + underline', { bold: true, underline: true })

pObj = docx.createP({ align: 'center' })

pObj.addText('Center this text', {
  border: 'dotted',
  borderSize: 12,
  borderColor: '88CCFF'
})

pObj = docx.createP()
pObj.options.align = 'right'

pObj.addText('Align this text to the right.')

pObj = docx.createP()

pObj.addText('Those two lines are in the same paragraph,')
pObj.addLineBreak()
pObj.addText('but they are separated by a line break.')

docx.putPageBreak()

pObj = docx.createP()

pObj.addText('Fonts face only.', { font_face: 'Arial' })
pObj.addText(' Fonts face and size.', { font_face: 'Arial', font_size: 40 })

docx.putPageBreak()

pObj = docx.createP()

// We can even add images:
pObj.addImage('some-image.png')

// Let's generate the Word document into a file:

let out = fs.createWriteStream('example.docx')

out.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err)
})

// Async call to generate the output file:
docx.generate(out)
```

Running:

> node generateReport.js

Would create a word document in the same folder of that file. The word document contains all the information detailed in the code.
Up until now, this works perfectly.
However, I have been struggling now for a couple of days to integrate that code in my Angular application, mainly because of the fs module.
First, I tried to implement that code in a normal Angular service. It didn't work.
After doing some research, I learned that:

> there's no way you can access  fs in the client.
>
> The problem is that js files running in your backend node.js
>   environment on a server are isolated from yours  front-end javascript
>   running inside the browser on a client machine. The only way, they can
>   communicate is  through HTTP calls. In order to do this, you need to
>   create a route, which can be reached from your client. Also,  you need
>   to pass parameters via query string: /save?url=path
>
> Angular applications run in the browser. Not in NodeJS on the server.
>   There is no access to the file  system in the browser, and you can't
>   use NodeJS-specific modules there

So it became clear why I was facing issues with fs.
Finally, here are my questions:
1/ What is the right way of implementing the generateReport code in my Angular app?
2/ Any tips for dealing with this front-end/back-end communications when it comes to files?
Thank you :)